# Get User Ranking based on number of posts (Codeigniter)

Tags: codeigniter

I have a number of users who are posting content to the POSTS Table.

```
id     user_id     content

1        1       text
2        3       text
3        1       text
4        1       text
5        2       text
6        3       text
```

Now, I would like to get a single user rank by highest posts(row). I'm confused about how to get the result!

Comment: How you could display that records? Can we see your query regarding on that?

Comment: what is your mean by highest?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue has been solved. Here is the explanation of how I've done this:

model

```
public function get_user_ranking()
{   

    $this->db->select('user_id, count(id) as total_posts');
    $this->db->group_by('user_id');
    $this->db->order_by('total_posts', 'DESC');
    $query = $this->db->get('posts');
    return $query->result();
}
```

controller

```
$data['user_ranking'] = $this->post_model->get_user_ranking();
```

view

```
$rank = 1; foreach($user_ranking as $row)
{
    if( $row->user_id == $user->id)
    {
        echo $rank;
        break;
    } 
    $rank++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Asuming that you are using the query builder, from the model, you can use the following statement to obtain the required result:

```
$this->db->select('user_id, count(content) as total_posts')
    ->group_by('user_id')
    ->order_by('total_posts', 'DESC')
    ->limit(1)
    ->get('POSTS')
    ->row();
```

Comment: getting error: here is my class get_user_ranking($user_id)

Comment: public function get_user_ranking($user_id)
    {
        $this->db->select('user_id, count(id) as total_posts')
    ->group_by('user_id')
    ->order_by('total_posts', 'DESC')
    ->limit(1)
    ->get('posts')
    ->row();
    }

Answer (score 0):

```
public function get_user_ranking()
{   

    $this->db->select('user_id, count(id) as total_postings');
    $this->db->from('posts');
    $this->db->group_by('user_id');
    $this->db->order_by('total_posts', 'DESC');
    return $this->db->get()->result();
}
```